# I want explanation in phpmyid and Openid

Tags: php, ssl, phpmyid

**what is phpmyid exactly? 
can I use it for logging into yahoo mail?
which steps I must follow?**

Well, basically OpenID is a way to authenticate yourself to various places (websites) by verifying your identity as the owner of a particular URL (say, a website of your own)

I can't understand it's explanation exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenID is a way of using one ID for multiple sites.  Think of it like using a Facebook login to register on multiple sites, just without the Facebook account.

The great thing about OpenID is that it's based on secure principles, and you only have to remember one password to identify yourself to any site that chooses to implement OpenID.

The problem, however, is that OpenID relies on OID providers.  If you want to maintain your own identity, you're pretty much out of luck.  You still have to hand over some of your identity to a third party who maintains your identity to serve it to any website which you authorize to use your identity to log you in.

PHPMyID allows you to essentially be your own identity provider.  Instead of registering on one centralized provider to maintain your profile, you set up [the script](http://siege.org/phpmyid.php) and run it on your own server.  This way, you retain control of your own identity, while still using one login for any website that supports OpenID.

Note, of course, that PHPMyID is no longer developed.

Comment: @Negin it uses HTTP Digest for communication and MD5 for internal hashing.  I don't actually know much about it other than what's on the link I provided.

Comment: phpMyID lets you do managing identity without giving control to a third party. but You are saying :If you want to maintain your own identity, you're pretty much out of luck. You still have to hand over some of your identity to a third party who maintains your identity to serve it to any website would you please explain?

Comment: @Negin that comment ("If you want to maintain your own identity, you're pretty much out of luck") is in reference to the immediately preceding sentence: "OpenID relies on OID providers."  The solution, therefore, is the **next** paragraph, which starts: "PHPMyID allows you to essentially be your own identity provider."

Comment: My results from your answer: PhpmyID is different from OpenID cause it's not needed for phpMyId using the 3rd party and another thing that I got was the more important thing that i didn't know using a unique Id for multiple sites I thought it is inverse multiple users with logging into 1 site you helped me Rockerest:)

Comment: @Negin remember, PHPMyID **is** an OpenID provider.  It still uses the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

phpmyid is a buggy, insecure and  unmaintained openid implementation that you should not bother with. See [this page](http://siege.org/phpmyid.php) for the juicy details.